# How do I pass an array of objects from Android to React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, kotlin

I'm trying to pass data into React Native from native Android. The data is an array of objects which consist of actions that should be dispatched.
Example

```
{
  "actions: [
    { 
      "authenticationType: "strong",
      "type: "AUTHENTICATION_URL",
      "url: "https://foo.bar/",
    },
  ],
}
```

I'm trying to use the `com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments` class to do something like

```
val arguments = Arguments.createMap().apply {
  putString("path", "general/authentication")  
  putArray("actions",
           Arguments.fromList(listOf(
                   mapOf("authenticationType" to "strong",
                         "type" to "AUTHENTICATION_URL",
                         "url" to url
                   ))))
}
```

but it only results in

```
09-14 20:08:53.996 10437 10437 I zygote  : Thread[1,tid=10437,Native,Thread*=0xb18da000,peer=0x73d2f568,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.getdreams-MO6VYrPeHVgAkBP2ori8SA==/lib/x86/libfb.so"
```

Unsure how to create that array of javascript objects.

Has anyone any suggestion of how to perhaps use [`com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/Arguments.java) in a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I did solve this only moments later by using the `Arguments` class, like so

```
val action = Arguments.makeNativeMap(
  mutableMapOf("authenticationType" to "strong",
               "type" to "AUTHENTICATION_URL",
               "url" to url) as Map<String, Any>)

val actionArray = Arguments.makeNativeArray(listOf(action))

val arguments = Arguments.createMap().apply {
    putString("path", "general/authentication")
    putArray("actions",actionArray)
}
```